# Rest API : save a value for later use for reasonable number of concurrent users

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

- I have a challenge in which i need to save a value and use it later for concurrent users.
- I have tried by using $request->ip() to store in DB and can retrieve--> Failed since its not in same network
- Browsed and found one more solution with Session and Cookie --> Failed since its rest API
- Tried apc_store cache method in php --> giving error undefined method in php 7 (laravel 7)

**Save Value** : This endpoint should allow the user to save a value for later use.

**Method**: POST

**Endpoint**: /save

**Body**: {"value": 12}

**Response** : {"save": true}

---

**Retrieve Value**
This endpoint should return the saved value

**Method**: GET

**Endpoint**: /savedValue

**Response** : {"value": 12}]

Can anyone give me a solution for this please

Comment: And whats exactly wrong with sessions in rest API? As long as it does not need to scale (and i'm assuming it doesn't, since this is just "a challenge") it's a simple and working solution.

Comment: @vicbyte : can u give a idea how to proceed in laravel php since i cannot use sessions. I am thinking in a way that how can i save value uniquely for concurrent users, so that i can retrieve later which means after few hours

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/session

Comment: @vicbyte : Storing sessions in DB is fine how can i fetch specific user values for concurrent users

Comment: You do realise there is a chapter in the link i provided named "Retrieving data", right?

Comment: @vicbyte : Yes i have seen it, I want to clarify for different type of users they get their values, which means one user should not get another user values. Its just for confirmation

Comment: Store in DB, map every value to a user in the "users" table (foreign key / a field in the table). Do `auth()->user()->stuff` to retrieve logged in user's data.

Comment: @qumber : Thanks for your response, i have used  sessions to store in DB and it worked